# Cannot call function from self on Array Extension Swift

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift

I am extending the `Array` class in swift. I need to sort the array, but when I try to it gives me the error `Immutable value of type 'Array<T>' only has mutating members named 'sort'`

Here is my extension:

```
import UIKit

extension Array {

    func sortedArrayByTimeUsingKey(key: String, ascending: Bool) {

        sort { (firstObject, secondObject) -> Bool in

            let firstDict = firstObject as [String: AnyObject]
            let secondDict = secondObject as [String: AnyObject]

            let firstDateString = firstDict[key]! as String
            let secondDateString = secondDict[key]! as String

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            let firstDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(firstDateString)!
            let secondDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(secondDateString)!

            let order = firstDate.compare(secondDate)

            switch order {
            case .OrderedAscending:
                return ascending ? true : false
            case .OrderedDescending:
                return ascending ? true : false
            default:
                return true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How can I cast `self` to be mutable or how can I check if `self` is mutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method modifies the instance itself, the method needs to be a mutating one. So just add the mutating keyword before func.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out the answer: add `mutating` before `func`